# Programmatically created visibility classes with SCSS

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I would like to create a set of classes based on the defined object with paired **keys** and **values**. The application of these classes doesn't really matter, but for the sake of this question let's say I would like to assign `display` value to `block` on some viewports and to `none` on another.

In code, desired **output** would be something like this:

```css
.visible-sm {
  display: none;
  @media screen and (max-width: 576px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.visible-md {
  display: none;
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 576px) {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.visible-lg {
  display: none;
  @media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is with the second media query condition (so the element is displayed **BETWEEN** some sizes, not **UP TO** or **DOWN TO** certain size).

What have I tried so far?

Declared the object with predefined breakpoints:

```
$viewport-breakpoints: (
  xs: 320px,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px
);
```

And loop through the object, creating the appropriate classes while trying to apply simple arithmetics

```
@each $breakpoint in $viewport-breakpoints {
  $breakpoint-down: #{nth($breakpoint - 1)};
  .visible-#{nth($breakpoint, 1)} {
    display: none;
    @media screen and (max-width: #{nth($breakpoint, 2)}) and (min-width: #{nth($breakpoint-down, 2)}) {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
}
```

I was hoping that `$breakpoint-down` variable will take the index of the iteration down (so if we're on `md`, will go `sm`, and so on), but unfortunately it will not work (won't compile, even).

If I would remove second media query condition it creates classes that let the elements be visible to certain breakpoints, however like I mentioned above I would like them to apply styling only between certain values.

**What am I missing?**

Let's not worry about the edge cases of the first and last pairs of the object for now. ;)

I've seen similar threads in here, where people explained how to loop with SCSS, but they only deal with lists, never with objects with paired keys and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're 90% of the way there. Your problem is `$breakpoint - 1` is invalid, because `$breakpoint` is not a number: in that context, `$breakpoint` is a key-value pair, for example `xs 320px`. Luckily we can access each part of that key-value pair using `nth()`:

```
$map: (
  xs: 320px,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px
);

@each $key, $val in $map {

  $index:                  index($map, $key $val);
  $previous-keyvalue-pair: nth($map, $index - 1);
  $previous-key:           nth($previous-keyvalue-pair, 1); // Not required for this question
  $previous-val:           nth($previous-keyvalue-pair, 2); // This is the one you need

  .visible-#{$key} {
    display: none;

    @if ($index > 1) { // To prevent accessing nth($map, 0) which would be invalid
      @media screen and (max-width: $val) and (min-width: $previous-val)) {
        display: block !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another way to write `$previous-val` would be `nth(nth($map, $index - 1), 2)`. [Here's a working example in SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/947dc3ad361f3ed70309057a21d4e281).

Comment: Thank you so much! To upgrade this great answer for a special case of the first pair (we don't need a special class for the last one really), we would just need a special if statement at the end of the block. :) Thank you a million!

Comment: For the first pair, I was considering adding a "blank" first entry to the map of breakpoints: `$map {0:0, xs: 320px, etc}` but I'm not sure if that does what you want. Anyway, glad I could help :)